# how to implement selection changed event in listpicker using mvvm pattern in wp8?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have a listpicker in which i have used interaction trigger to fire selection changed event.But it is showing Xaml  parse exception error.

The code in xaml page is:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPickerAccount" ItemsSource="{Binding AccountTypeList,Mode=TwoWay}">                               
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
              <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding AccountTypeSelectionCommand}"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listPickerAccount}"> 

              </i:InvokeCommandAction>
          </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I have set property in viewmodel as

```
public ICommand AccountTypeSelectionCommand
{
   get
   {
     return new RelayCommand<object>((x) =>
     {
          string item = (string)(x as ListPicker).SelectedItem;
          ListPickerSelection(item);
     });
   }
}

private void ListPickerSelection(string item)
{
  if (AccountType != null)
  {
      AccountType = item;
      return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your InvokeCommandAction update CommandParameter like this : `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listPickerAccount, Path=SelectedItem}"`

Try this and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

//Xaml

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
                    <command:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding TestCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="">
                    </command:EventToCommand>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

//VIewModel

```
public RelayCommand TestCommand{ get; set; } 

TestCommand= new RelayCommand( TestMethode);  

    private void TestMethode( SelectionChangedEventArgs args )  
    {  
        //TODO   args.AddItems can be help 
    }
```

Comment: But property 'PassEventArgsToComand' is not present in InvokeCommandAction